# Retrieve Hydration data from google fit

Tags: android, google-fit

I am trying to implement a water reminder and glass count in my app. Googlefit recently included Datatype [Hydration](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType.html#TYPE_HYDRATION). But there is no field from which to retrieve historical hydration data. [List of fields](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/Field).

This is the code I am trying to implement to retrieve hydration info:

```
PendingResult<DailyTotalResult> result =
   HistoryApi.readDailyTotalFromLocalDevice(client, AGGREGATE_HYDRATION);
DailyTotalResult totalResult = result.await(30, SECONDS);
if (totalResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
   DataSet totalSet = totalResult.getTotal();
   long total = totalSet.isEmpty()
     ? 0
     : totalSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(<<??What should come here??>>).asInt();
} else {
   // handle failure
}
```

Will I have to make a custom datatype and field to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Hydration stores the volume of water consumed. So field type would be `FIELD. FIELD_VOLUME` in the `getValue()` method